# 7 Column grid in bootstrap collapse at xs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, multiple-columns

I really like this code [pen](http://codepen.io/knitevision1/pen/BAFmk/) and I'd like to use it to create a calendar, however I need it to collapse at `screen-xs` using bootstrap and I am not sure how to do it.

I have tried adding `.seven-cols .col-xs-1` and `.seven-cols .col-xs-12` but it still just breaks into two points.

I'm also having trouble understanding the CSS.

Comment: Try this class `hidden-xs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use bootstrap for rendering a calendar I suggest you to compile a custom version by changing the number of columns. The default value of 12 columns is not practical, so change it with 14 here (input "@grid-columns"): http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system

If you want to keep the original bootstrap, use 1 column for each day, and an offset for the first day: http://jsfiddle.net/wj635bsr/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="day col-md-1 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="day-title">Monday</div>
    </div>

    ...

</div>
```

I this example, I use col-md-* because col-xs-* as a different behaviour: (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)